# Testing Spring MVC Restful Webservices No UI

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, soapui

What can be used to test web services that does not have a user interface? I've been reading around that junit and soapUI can do the trick. However, I am looking for something powerful and flexible. Will any of these do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring comes with the spring-test module which provides a MockMvc (further reading -> https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html). For me it is flexible enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Use JUnit and [Apache-Components/HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/) for low level integration testing.

For a more highlevel (not integration testing) use [Spring MVC Test Framework](https://spring.io/blog/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework)

Answer (score 1):

in our project we are using mokito and springs SpringJUnit4ClassRunner